# Cannot call methods on iconList prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'getColumns'

Tags: jquery, oracle-apex

I am using APEX 20.2. I am trying to call `getColumns()` method of `iconList` widget. I run the page then change the view to `icon` view then call the method using `apex.region('IG').widget().interactiveGrid('getViews','icon').view$.iconList('getColumns');` but I face error: `cannot call methods on iconList prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'getColumns'` How should I initialize the iconList widget?

Comment: Is that a js console error?

Comment: Yes it is a JS console error.

Comment: This often happens when you lose context or when there is a modal window involved. Try searching stack for Cannot call methods on prior to initialization; attempted to call method context this self.  Sometimes simply updating the jQuery version solves the problem.  Can you post more of your code?  Is there an AJAX call?

Comment: Fortunately, there is no other code. It's just that line. No AJAX calls. What do you mean with "context" in "lose context"? I see that word from time to time and I can not figure out what it means!